# PHP query preforming without errors, but not posting to MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql

Having trouble with getting my data to post to MySQL server. Looking for an extra set of eyes to tell me why it's not posting! Below I have `testpost.php` which allows the user to enter in a name and email and post it to my `welcome.php` page which then creates a connection to my sql server which is set up in `mysqli_connect.php`

```js
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "test";

$conn = new
mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$database);
if($conn->connect_error){
die("Connection failed:" . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected Sucessfully";
?>
```

```css
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<?php

require_once 'mysqli_connect.php';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$query = "INSERT INTO test_table (name,email) VALUES('$name', '$email')";
?>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"];
  ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you need to fix this.

Comment: Simply practicing. this is not any type of production application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not executing your query .

After setting $query you need:

$conn->query($query);

Comment: That would only make sense huh! Thanks buddy, Have a good night. Will accept the answer asap